# Trigger using data from inserted row

Tags: postgresql

I need to write a function that triggers each time a new row is inserted into my table named `users`. The table has three columns: `name, surname, id`. Each time a new user is added, I want to automatically trigger `CREATE USER`, where the username is the id from the newly inserted row. For example, if I add a row with `John, Smith, jsmith`, I want a new user named `jsmith`.
How can I use `NEW` in CREATE USER, so that, like in the example, it creates a user with the username jsmith?

Comment: Which part of the function are you particularly having trouble with? Are you looking for how to [execute dynamically defined SQL statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)?

Comment: I think that's the thing I need, though I do have a problem with my function:
`create or replace function newuser() returns trigger as $$
begin
execute create user $1 in group users using new.id;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;`
I get an error in the `create` line.

Comment: You have two big mistakes there: you aren't giving `EXECUTE` a string, just a bunch of unquoted keywords; and you can't use `$1` to substitute in identifiers or other parameters for statements like `CREATE USER`, only the data in `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the pl/pgsql [`EXECUTE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> EXECUTE command-string [ INTO [STRICT] target ] [ USING expression [, ... ] ];

This takes a string, which you can build up however you like. So in your case, you need to concatenate a fixed piece of SQL (the words `CREATE USER`, and any options you want to pass to configure the user) with a variable based on the inserted row (from the `NEW` record).

As the manual mentions, it's important when creating dynamic SQL to quote input appropriately for its context, in this case, using the `quote_ident` function to quote the username.

So your trigger function might look roughly like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'CREATE USER ' || quote_ident(NEW.id) || ' NOLOGIN';
    END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. What if I want to use the surname as a password in the function?

Comment: @photons3432 I refer you to this sentence: "a string, which you can build up however you like". In case it's not familiar, `||` is the SQL concatenation operator - it just glues two strings together to make a longer string. Glue as many strings as you want together, call as many other functions, invent as many other variables, then pass the result to `EXECUTE`, and it will, well, execute it.